# How to Share a SharePoint list item to specific external user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I am trying to give access to a specific external user for a list item and the user is not added as a guest yet. How can we perform this using Power Automate/SharePoint Rest API.

Note: Since it is a dynamic process, I cannot add them manually.

Answer (score 1):

Per my research, 'Create sharing link for a file or folder' only supports files or folders in a document library. List items are not supported yet. You can refer to following document.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/manage-list-item-file-permissions

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved.